# How to set the language of the apache/superset in docker

Tags: docker, business-intelligence, apache-superset

I want to set the superset language to Chinese. I found the configuration items of [BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset/config.py#L271) in the code. How to set the BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE value in docker.

Comment: What did you try so far? How do you launch your container? Have you look at the options of `docker container run`? There is a `--env` that may be useful in your case. Or have you look at the documentation of docker-compose? There is an `environment` that could do the job.

Comment: @zigarn i use this docker-compose file in apache/superset project. 
https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker-compose-non-dev.yml

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment and in this specific docker-compose file you can see that it's using `env_file` https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file

Comment: @zigarn Thank you, I have found a way. I can create a superset_config.py to add to PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.x: Very simple, set BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'zh' in superset_config.py file.